# Calculate grid layout based on connections?

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

It's easiest if I explain this backwards. I want to calculate this:

```
1  |  2
-------
3  |  4
```

when I'm given a list of connected edges between nodes. So, in this example:

- 1 <-> 2
- 1 <-> 3
- 2 <-> 1
- 2 <-> 4
- 3 <-> 1
- 3 <-> 4

I'm aware that the layout could be a number of different alternatives (imagine rotating it 90 degrees), but that's OK. I've played around with [D3 force layouts](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout) which gets part of the way there, but I want the results to be connected on strict 90 degree angles rather than as loosely connected nodes.

I'm not too sure where to start approaching this problem (or what any of the terms that apply to it might be) - any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

The layout you want is known as an *orthogonal graph layout* (or drawing) without bends. (A variant: "no-bend orthogonal drawing".) The paper [Orthogonal Drawings of Plane Graphs Without Bends](http://jgaa.info/getPaper?id=74) by Md. Saidur Rahman, Takao Nishizeki, and Mahmuda Naznin  describes  an algorithm. I don't know of any JavaScript implementation of it.